# Como manipular diferentes dados do combobox em tempo de execução

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um campo textfield e uma combobox ao lado dela...

**Segue a imagem**

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero fazer com que, dado o valor no campo **textfield**, quero que ao clicar em **outro item do combobox**, seja convertido o valor **no textfield** para o elemento correspondente(o escolhido no combo).

Alguém pode me dar um norte?

Comment: você tem dois eventos no comboBox: `SelectedIndexChanged` ou `SelectedValueChanged` Basta manipular esses eventos. Se quiser mais detalhes, coloque o código de como você preenche seu comboBox

Comment: Mas antes disso estou c um problema, em como implementar a classe que faz as conversões...

Comment: `8796,3 H2O(g) > X oz(g)` por exemplo ?

Comment: Sim...
Exemplo: Quero por um valor ali no textField e aí preenchido o valor, quero ver como ele irá ficar se ele for convertido em outra unidade...
Logo clicando no combobox e selecionado outra unidade, quero que traga o valor convertido, na qual a unidade foi selecionada no combo.

Comment: Tipo,

Coloco a pressão: 50 e a unidadeDaPressão: H2O(g)

ai dps indo no combobox e mudando para oz(g), traga o valor atualizado e convertido no txtfield...

Sou novo c dev, n to conseguindo fluir...

Comment: então, acho que a pergunta deve ser outra, e mostre o código que você tem pronto, quais unidades seriam e pra adiantar o lado do pessoal aqui, qual o calculo pra conversão. Informe também se essas unidades são fixas no sistema, ou podem ser cadastradas

Comment: Aqui o que eu tenho... https://ghostbin.com/paste/tn36t
E essas unidades são fixas no sistema, não há nenhum lugar onde elas são cadastradas.

Comment: Algum progresso ?

Comment: Sim, consegui resolver.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pergunta não está muito específica, mas foi esclarecida nos comentários.

Sua real necessidade seria a conversão de unidades ao mudar o valor do combobox.

Com base no código passado, fiz o seguinte código, que contempla apenas 3 unidades, porém tem suporte para adicionar quantas forem necessárias.

1. Ao invés de definir as unidades como string, podemos defini-las como um enumerable:

   ```
   public enum PressUnit
   {
       [Description("Atm")]
       Atm = 1,
       [Description("Psi")]
       Psi = 2,
       [Description("Kpa")]
       Kpa = 3
   }
   ```
2. Classe propriamente dita, que realiza o calculo de conversão e tem um dicionário com os valores indexados pela unidade `atm`:

   ```
   public class Press
   {
       public Press()
       {
           Valor = 1;
           Unidade = PressUnit.Atm;
       }

       public PressUnit Unidade { get; private set; }
       public decimal Valor { get; private set; }

       public void SetValor(decimal _valor, PressUnit _unidade)
       {
           this.Unidade = _unidade;
           this.Valor = _valor;
       }

       public void SetValor(decimal _valor)
       {
           this.Valor = _valor;
       }

       public bool ConvertTo(PressUnit _unidade)
       {
           decimal c = 0;
           if (TabelaAtm.TryGetValue(this.Unidade, out c))
           {
               decimal atm = this.Valor / c;

               decimal d = 0;
               if (TabelaAtm.TryGetValue(_unidade, out d))
               {
                   this.Unidade = _unidade;
                   this.Valor = atm * d;
                   return true;
               }
               else
                   return false;
           }
           else return false;
       }

       public static Dictionary<PressUnit, decimal> TabelaAtm = new Dictionary<PressUnit, decimal>()
       {
           {PressUnit.Atm,1},
           {PressUnit.Psi,(decimal)14.6959},
           {PressUnit.Kpa,(decimal)101.325}
       };
   }
   ```
3. Para utilizar o atributo description do enum com mais facilidade, utilizo esse método de extensão:

   ```
   static class Extension
   {
       public static string GetEnumDescription<TEnum>(this TEnum item)
       {
           DescriptionAttribute x = item.GetType().GetField(item.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
           .Cast<DescriptionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
           return x == null ? String.Empty : x.Description;
       }
   }
   ```

> **Utilização:**

**Form1.cs**

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Press objPress;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            objPress = new Press();
            //comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PressUnit));
            GetComboUnidades();
        }
        private void GetComboUnidades()
        {
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
            comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PressUnit))
                .Cast<Enum>()
                .Select(value => new
                {
                    Description = value.GetEnumDescription(),
                    value
                })
                .OrderBy(item => item.value)
                .ToList();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "0";
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                objPress.ConvertTo((PressUnit)comboBox1.SelectedValue);
                textBox1.Text = objPress.Valor.ToString("N3");
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                objPress.SetValor(Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text), (PressUnit)comboBox1.SelectedValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

***Resultado:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Não estou em casa agora pra ver isso, amanhã no trabalho irei ver o que você me passou, mas de cara, era exatamente isso que eu queria. De qualquer forma, muito obrigado mesmo pela sua atenção. Araços!